# Not Moq-ing C# Stream properly, causing EndOfStream to be true the first time

Tags: c#, csv, mocking

In my Test case:

```
Mock<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadedFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.InputStream)
                .Returns(fileStream);

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.InputStream.Position)
                .Returns(741);

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.InputStream.CanRead)
                .Returns(true);

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.FileName)
                .Returns(csvFilePath);

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.ContentLength)
                .Returns(contentLength);

            uploadedFile
                .Setup(f => f.InputStream.Length)
                .Returns(contentLength);

            var result = await _assetController.UploadData(assetId, uploadedFile.Object);
```

Where csvFilePath leads to a legitimate CSV file.

I suspect I am not Moq-ing properly because in the following:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadCsvFileAsync(Stream fileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileContents = String.Empty;
                fileStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {

                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        fileContents = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                } 
    //.. snip
```

Whenever I try to process the uploaded CSV file, **the `EndOfStream` flag is always true the first time**.

[Can I get StreamReader.EndOfStream to return false after the first time I read a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525383/can-i-get-streamreader-endofstream-to-return-false-after-the-first-time-i-read-a) This thread describes my predicament in a way, but as I said, I think I might not have setup my Moq-ing correctly (perhaps I am missing a crucial `.Setup(f => f.<Property>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an actual stream to fake the available data.

```
//Arrange
HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFile = Mock.Of<HttpPostedFileBase>();
var mock = Mock.Get(httpPostedFile);
mock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(csvFilePath);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
//...TODO: populate fake stream with data

//setup mock to return stream
mock.Setup(_ => _.InputStream).Returns(memoryStream);
mock.Setup(_ => _.ContentLength).Returns(memoryStream.Length);

//...setup any other desired behavior

//Act
var result = await _assetController.UploadData(assetId, httpPostedFile);

//Assert
//...Assert code here
```

Comment: Thanks. Incorporating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397565/how-to-load-entire-stream-into-memorystream has helped to complete the code I needed.